# rank over partition

Tags: sql, teradata, window-functions

I have a total of 3 tables. One table is called `CONTACTINFO` with `CNTCT_ID` as a primary index.

Second table is `CONTACTMAP` which links a customer(`CUSTNUM`) to all the contactinfo (details suchs as name, position, phone number etc).

Final table is a complete customer list, with one column that has a revolving list of all our customers.

My code below pulls back the most recent entry for `custnum` 84574. But I need it pull back results for all `custnum` in the complete customer list `custlist`.

```
select 
     A. CUST_TYPE
    ,A.CINSERT_DT
    ,A.CNTCT_ID

from CONTACTINFO a

JOIN  CONTACTMAP B
ON A.CNTCT_ID = B.CNTCT_ID

where       b. CUSTNUM in (‘84574’)
and         A. CUST_TYPE in (‘PAYER’)

qualify rank() over (partition by a. CUST_TYPE order by A. CINSERT_DT desc) = 1
```

Here are my tables
`CONTACTINFO TABLE`

```
CNTCT_ID    CUST_TYPE
1           PAYER
2           OWNER
3           BUYER
```

`CONTACTMAP Table`

```
 CNTCT_ID       CUSTNUM
1           84574
2           99457   
3           54187
```

`TABLE3`

```
 CUSTNUM
84574
99457   
54187
```

Comment: I don't get it. Can you show table #3 especially *one column that has a revolving list of all our customers*?

Comment: Updated with table3, @dnoeth

Comment: Simply join #3 on `CUSTNUM` and change the `PARTITION BY` to `CUSTNUM` instead of `CUST_TYPE` (Or use both if you want one row per type)

Comment: @dnoeth That was exactly what I needed. Thank you for the assistance. If you want to add this as an answer instead of a comment, I'd be happy to accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply join table #3 on CUSTNUM and change the PARTITION BY to CUSTNUM instead of CUST_TYPE:

```
select 
     A. CUST_TYPE
    ,A.CINSERT_DT
    ,A.CNTCT_ID

from CONTACTINFO a

JOIN  CONTACTMAP B
ON A.CNTCT_ID = B.CNTCT_ID
JOIN custlist as c
ON b.CUSTNUM = c. CUSTNUM

--maybe remove the condition and add CUST_TYPE to PARTITION BY if you want one row per type
where A.CUST_TYPE in (‘PAYER’)

qualify
  rank()
  over (partition by c.CUSTNUM 
        order by CINSERT_DT desc) = 1
```